# Integrate Facebook leads Ads into another platform

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I am developing a web app which allows marketers to publish campaigns and generate leads. I want to integrate Facebook leads ads platform into my web app so that I can allow marketers to publish campaigns on both platforms. For this, I need some resources or developers API from developers.Facebook.com. I have extensively search there but no success. Can someone point me to specific developer guide regarding Facebook leads ads?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Webhook in you app that triggers when a new lead is made.

The steps I took go along [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/webhooks/v2.5).

Just make an API endpoint where Facebook Webhook can

```
GET
```

And

```
POST
```

Then when your Webhook is alive (this is what the GET is for) you can receive the Lead info in the POST Facebook makes to your endpoint.

Some code to give you context (Node.js using Express):

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./facebook.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.post('/', controller.webhook);

module.exports = router;
```

The GET endpoint

```
// Confirm token that was set in the Webhook setup 
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
  var challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'],
    verify_token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
  if (verify_token === 'YOUR_TOKEN') {
    res.send(challenge);
  }
};
```

The POST endpoint

```
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');
var fb = require('fb'); 
fb.setAccessToken('acces_token');
var getResponseAPI = require('getresponse-nodejs-api')('API_KEY');

exports.webhook = function(req, res) {
  var leadName, leadEmail;
  // Lead Info 
  var fbChanges = req.body.entry[0].changes;
  var getLeadFromFacebook = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (fbChanges !== undefined) {
      fbChanges.forEach(function(item, index) {
        //You need to retrieve the User info from the changes because Facebook Just gives you UID
        var getUserInfoFromGraph = new Promise(
          function(resolve, reject) {
            var leadId = item.value.leadgen_id;
            fb.api(leadId.toString(), function(res) {
              if (!res || res.error) {
                console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
                reject(res.error);
              }
              resolve(res);
            });

          }
        );
        getUserInfoFromGraph.then(function(userInfo) {
          //To give you a picture the content of the data
          console.log(JSON.stringify(userInfo.field_data));
          userInfo.field_data.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item.name === 'full_name') {
              leadName = item.values[0];
            } else if (item.name === 'email') {
              leadEmail = item.values[0];
            }
          });
        }).then(function(leadInfo) {
          //Work with info here I'm using getResponse :)
          getResponseAPI.addContact('CAMPAIGN_ID', leadName, leadEmail, null, 0, {}, function(response) {
            if (response.data.error) {
              console.log('Error' + response.data.error.message);
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
          });

        });
      });
    } else {
      res.status(400);
    }
  });
};
```